# Using a $variable inside another $variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

```
$var_name = 'name';

$results = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1") or die (mysql_error ());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($results);

$username = $row[$$var_name];
```

How is it possible to use the $variable within this mysql result?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: If $var_name equals the name of a coloumn, that's perfectly right. 

However, I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: Your code looks good. What's not working?

Comment: It would be safer to wrap your assignment with an `if (isset($row[$var_name]))`, as this would let you know if the row is not found (either because the column does not exist, or because there are no records for ID 1).

Comment: you have to define the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

What I took from this was that you are trying to assign the result of the query to a variable for later use?  Something like a username, password, address, city, state, zip, etc.  To do that you would do something like the following.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())

//now assign the variables
for($row = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $row++)
{
    //assign variables
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $zip = $row['zip'];

    //etc...
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a loop though so if you end up with two results from your query then the variables will be different with each loop.  This type of setup is good for displaying multiple rows of data.  There are other methods you could use to set the variables you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like

```
${$var_name}
```

But this is not the best way... If $var_name come from the request you can produce critical leaks!

In your example it should be:

```
$var_name = 'name';
$username = $row[${$var_name}];  // same as : $username = $row[$name];
```

Once more: NOT recommended!